# bash `mv -n` detect if not overwritten

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I tried searching but couldn't find a similar question. If this is a duplicate, please let me know and I'll gladly remove it.

I've got a script for renaming files inside of a loop, running:

```
mv -vn "$file" $newname
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    *do something*
fi
```

With `-v` I can see on the screen `xxx not overwritten`, but I'm trying to detect when a file is not renamed by the script due to a file with the same name already existing.

The `mv` utility exits `0` on success, which is the case whether the file is renamed or not.

Any pointers?

Comment: Can't you just use `ls` on the filename before you try to move? `ls` will return different values for `file does not exist` and `file does exist`.

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu Ughhh... No, don't parse `ls` output. However, something like `if [[ -a "${newname}" ]]; then ...` would work to check if the file exists.

Comment: @twalberg - Race condition.

Comment: @TomZych True, but I'm not entirely sure what the OP is looking for can be done entirely race-free in `bash`, at least not without sacrificing a significant amount of simplicity and/or performance... And it's no worse than the other comments/answers in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the file exists, if not rename:

`test -e $newname || mv $file $newname`

If you need message saying xxx not overwritten:

```
test -e $newname && echo "$newname not overwritten" || mv $file $newname
```

Comment: Wow I had the blinders on...I should have been thinking along these lines...thanks!

Comment: @TomZych do you mean that in the interval between the `test` and `mv`  a file may have been created?

Comment: @Tiago - yes. Granted this is more of a concern in an automated context than with this sort of manual tool, but you never know how something will end up being used.